Default MaxConcurrentCall property for a service bus is per queue or for all queues in a azure webjobs service bus sdk
We are using Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extension.ServiceBs 5.0.0.0 and are not specifying mazconcurrentCalls properts
we have several service bus trigger classes listening to different queues of one single service bus
will each queue use 16 concurrent thread to process the messages parallely or all queues will use 16threads in total to process the message
Eg:
public static class A
{
    public static void A(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("sendexpiryemailqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ExpiryEmailQueueEntity expiryEmailQueueEntity,
        [Table("DisallowedFunctionsInventory", Connection = "TableStorageConnection")] TableClient disabledFunctionsTable,
        ILogger logger)
    {

}}

 public class B
 {
        public static void B(
[ServiceBusTrigger("expiringpowerportalqueue", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string entity,
[Table("DisallowedFunctionsInventory", Connection = "TableStorageConnection")] TableClient disabledFunctionsTable,
ILogger logger)
        {

}

We are using Microsoft.Azure.Webjobs.Extension.ServiceBs 5.0.0.0 and are not specifying mazconcurrentCalls properts
we have several service bus trigger classes listening to different queues of one single service bus
will each queue use 16 concurrent thread to process the messages parallely or all queues will use 16threads in total to process the message

I used MSDOC for concurrency in Azure Functions.
Azure Functions has two main types of concurrency:

Static Concurrency: You can manually define restrictions on the number of concurrent executions. This is configured per trigger type.
Dynamic Concurrency: Modifies concurrency levels automatically in response to workload and instance health in real-time.

Here's a detailed explanation:
Static Concurrency
The default model for static concurrency defines concurrency limits manually for each type of trigger.

Trigger for Service Bus: The maximum number of concurrent messages that may be handled on each instance is determined by the MaxConcurrentCalls parameter. By default, it is set to 16 concurrent calls per instance unless specified otherwise.

The maximum number of concurrent calls to the callback that the message pump should initiate can be limited using maxConcurrentCalls. The Functions runtime handles many messages at once by default. If set to 1, it will handle only one queue or topic message at a time.
The configuration is as follows:
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "serviceBus": {
            "prefetchCount": 10,
            "messageHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:03:00"
            },
            "sessionHandlerOptions": {
                "autoComplete": true,
                "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:60",
                "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:50:00",
                "maxConcurrentSessions": 1
            }
        }
    }
}



HTTP Trigger (Flexible Consumption Plan): The concurrency depends on the instance size. For example:

2048 MB instance size: 16 concurrent requests.
4096 MB instance size: 32 concurrent requests.



For functions using static concurrency, you must configure these settings in the host.json file. The limits apply to each instance, and if you have multiple instances, each can handle up to the configured number of concurrent executions.
Dynamic Concurrency
Dynamic Concurrency adjusts concurrency levels automatically based on real-time metrics and system load. This model is designed to simplify concurrency management and improve function performance.

Enabling Dynamic Concurrency: You can enable it in your host.json file with the following settings:



{
    "version": "2.0",
    "concurrency": {
        "dynamicConcurrencyEnabled": true,
        "snapshotPersistenceEnabled": true
    }
}





dynamicConcurrencyEnabled: Enables automatic adjustment of concurrency.

snapshotPersistenceEnabled: Stores learned concurrency values to optimize startup times for new instances.

Supported Triggers: Dynamic concurrency is supported for Azure Blob, Azure Queue, and Service Bus triggers.



In this example, the always-ready instance count for the HTTP triggers group is changed to 10 using the az functionapp scale config always-ready set command:

az functionapp scale config always-ready set --resource-group <RESOURCE_GROUP_Name> --name <FunctionAPP_NAME> --settings http=10

This command is only valid for Azure Functions on the Flexible Consumption plan.

